# windows phone 7 Saving image and sound in database

Tags: database, image, windows-phone-7, audio, local-database

I am currently doing my final year project. I have to create a Windows phone application. My application allows users to record sound and image and store it in their windows phone database. I know that in order for us to store image and sound in the database which uses SQL ce we have to convert them to byte. The problem that i am currently facing is that once the image is saved and when i try to retrieve it, the picture is a black image. I am also not sure on how to save the sound in the database. If it is not much trouble, could please help me? i am really new to windows phone development and i am not sure about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Id save everything to isolated storage and just store the location of said data in a database. You'll find this much easier :-)

Comment: i already created a local database..my project requires me to save the images and sound in a database

Comment: The project requires you to store the bit data itself?

Comment: yes, we are suppose to save image and sound in the database, and i found most of the websites stating i have to convert the image and sound into bytes and save it in the database